# Can I use a standard flex cable to extend the sensor module cable in a GoPro 11 Mini?

Tags: camera, video, hacking, fpc, ffc

I would like to heavily modify a GoPro 11 Mini, one aspect of the modifications I have in mind is to relocate the sensor module. The issue with this is that it's flex cable is very short so I would need to extend it somehow. The simplest method I can think of is to connect a standard flex cable to the end of the original one.

However the design of the original cable appears quite complex, featuring multiple layers and a cross hatching pattern, so I fear that a standard cable will cause issues for example due to EMI or certain traces no longer being on separate layers.

Here is a picture of the kind of cable I'm considering and the sensor module:

[image: 0.3mm 45 pin FFC]

Comment: I guess, nobody can answer this. My opinion is: Make sure, there are no active parts on the flex (Transreceivers etc - is common), make sure to use "the same" impedance and buy different lengths (e.g 25mm,50mm,100mm and so on) and then just try. Place it close to a micro-wave or a wifi-router and check if there are issues - if not: Your Handy-Man EMI-robust flex extension is finished.